# "No accessor to set property private final java.util.Map org.json.JSONObject.map!"+SpringBoot REST API

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, microservices

I used SpringBoot REST API microservice.
In GET Method, I try get All scores, but in the Postman when I use GET, i'd getting this error in the console

```
"No accessor to set property private final java.util.Map org.json.JSONObject.map!"
```

I guess, this problem is because of JSONARRAY that I used in my Score Class as a type for history object, but I do not know how can I fix it.
The Score Class:

```
@Document(collection = "score")
public class Score {
    @Id
    @NotBlank
    @JsonView(Views.class)
    private String scoreid;
    @JsonView(Views.class)
    private Long score;
    @NotBlank
    @JsonView(Views.class)
    private String player;
    @NotBlank
    @JsonView(Views.class)
    private String gamecode;
    @JsonView(Views.class)
    private Date date;
    public JSONArray history;
    
    
    
    public Score(@NotBlank String scoreid, Long score, @NotBlank String player, @NotBlank String gamecode, Date date,
            JSONArray history) {
        super();
        this.scoreid = scoreid;
        this.score = score;
        this.player = player;
        this.gamecode = gamecode;
        this.date = date;
        this.history = history;
    }
    public String getScoreid() {
        return scoreid;
    }
    public void setScoreid(String scoreid) {
        this.scoreid = scoreid;
    }
    public Long getScore() {
        return score;
    }
    public void setScore(Long score) {
        this.score = score;
    }
    public String getPlayer() {
        return player;
    }
    public void setPlayer(String player) {
        this.player = player;
    }
    public String getGamecode() {
        return gamecode;
    }
    public void setGamecode(String gamecode) {
        this.gamecode = gamecode;
    }
    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }
    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
    
    public JSONArray getHistory() {
        return history;
    }
    public void setHistory(JSONArray history) {
        this.history = history;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Score [scoreid=" + scoreid + ", score=" + score + ", player=" + player + ", gamecode=" + gamecode + "]";
    }
    

}
```

The score Controller:

```
 public class ScoreController {
    @Autowired
    private ScoreRepository srepo;
    @Autowired
    private PlayerRepository prepo;
    @Autowired
    private GameRepository grepo;
    
    //POST NEW SCORE
    @PostMapping("/score")
    public ResponseEntity<?> createScore(@RequestBody @JsonView(Views.class) @Valid  Score score) {
        Player p = prepo.findByNickname(score.getPlayer());
        Game g = grepo.findByCode(score.getGamecode());
        if ((srepo.findByScoreid(score.getScoreid())) == null) {
            if((p!= null) && (g!=null)) {
            
            JSONObject jo = new JSONObject();
            jo.put("score", score.getScore());
            jo.put("date", score.getDate());
            JSONArray ja = new JSONArray();
            ja.put(jo);
            score.setHistory(ja);           
            srepo.save(score);
            return ResponseEntity.status(201).body("Created!");
            }
            else return ResponseEntity.status(400).body("Bad Request!");
        }
        
        else
            return ResponseEntity.status(409).body("Conflict!");
        }
    //GET ALL SCORES
    @GetMapping("/score")
    public List<Score> getAllScores(){
        return srepo.findAll();
    }
```

And inside the Application.properties I used :

```
spring.jackson.serialization.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS=false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use JSONArray to implement a list attribute. Instead of it use a java.util.List or array and jackson will serialize it as JsonArray without problem.

Probably it will fix the problem. You will have to declare also the object containing the history information and define the accessors (getters, and setters) on it

Comment: In fact, I wanted to have an array of json, but with your suggestion i could have something which is similar and it is near to what i want.thank you